# Firebase reset password using provider accounts

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for a little while and I find a little issue I think it's not a big issue, that issue is that when I login with provider account like: "facebook" account and I enter facebook account email in forgot password field this should show an error but what happens is that the method success, my question is that when I reset password is my facebook account password changed or what happens, heres my method below:

```
 mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){Toast.makeText(forgot.this,"Send",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();mProgress.hide();}
                    else {Toast.makeText(forgot.this,"Not send",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();mProgress.hide();}}});}
```

I need a method that check if user email is an provider email like "facebook,twitter and google" and return.

So any help brothers.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an API to check what type of provider is associated with an email, you can use fetchProvidersForEmail.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#fetchProvidersForEmail(java.lang.String)

As for resetting the password of an account that had a Facebook provider linked to it, it will unlink that Facebook account and transform it into a password account. The user will need to re-link the Facebook provider. This behavior allows the user to recover an account in case it was hijacked and modified by another unverified user.

Comment: Seems that method has changed since, you can now use [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String))

Comment: I'm having problems right at this point - the login method changes to Email after resetting a password. Then how is it linked back to Facebook? After a successful Facebook login, I use the token to login in the backend and it seems to work (no exception raised), but the token is empty (using PHP Firebase Admin SDK: that's signInResult->idToken(), normally it contains a good Firebase token, but not in the described scenario)