# Firebase reset password issue for users with social media authentication

Tags: android, ios, firebase, passwords, reset

I am trying to reset password for Firebase in iOS for a user who has email authentication as well as Facebook and Twitter authentication in Firebase.

The password is reset successfully and the user ID is the same, but the user's Facebook and Twitter authentication is removed (see below). How do I reset password in Firebase without removing social media authentication?

User authentication with social media linking before password reset


[image]

User authentication with social media unlinked after password reset


[image]

This issue also occur on Android

Comment: Could you supply the code you use to reset the password (including the authorization part)?

Answer (score 4):

The following reply from a Googler seems to indicate that the unlinking is an intended consequence of the password reset to allow the user to recover their account in the case it was hijacked and modified by another user:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694017/1171539

Answer (score 0):

First I would check the method they used to sign in:

> You can lookup the providers linked to an account using: fetchProvidersForEmail
>   To reset the password, use: sendPasswordResetWithEmail
>   There are also instructions on how to send the password reset and redirect back to app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions

see [Firebase forgot password- how to identify whether user signed in with email or facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023909/firebase-forgot-password-how-to-identify-whether-user-signed-in-with-email-or-f)

Once you know the sign in method, if the method is email/password, you can call to specifically reset the password with email only. If it's social media then you can just not reset it, or ask the user to unlink the account, reset the password of the account, and relink the account if you're really determined.

Have you tried that?

Comment: If you check their log in method on log in you can simply have this "work around" to show the ui for reset password or if it is a social media account, to not show it. The user experience will only change based on the reset button being there or not, but you can't reset the password of social media site through firebase anyway...