# Firebase forgot password- how to identify whether user signed in with email or facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

This is my scenario. I am developing a `firebase login` iOS app. For this i am using `Email & Password Authentication` and `facebook authentication`. Lets assume if user knows his email but forgot the password. How can i identify if the user logged in with facebook or email, and how to reset the password?  i searched a lot. But could not find a solution for that. can anyone help me.

Comment: Do you need to? If they logged in from FB don't you just send a reset password email to the registered email, and therefore never need to know if they are registered through FB or password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lookup the providers linked to an account using:
[fetchProvidersForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#fetchprovidersforemailcompletion)

To reset the password, use: [sendPasswordResetWithEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#sendpasswordresetwithemailcompletion)

There are also instructions on how to send the password reset and redirect back to app: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. Whenever a user signs up with your platform, be sure to save their basic information e.g. `email`, `name`, `photoURL`, `signup/loginType`, `user-id` etc to a database of your choice i.e `Firebase Firestore` or the `Realtime Database(RTD)`.

So you could have the following Scheme in the `RTD` for instance:

```
my-app
  ----users
  --------user-id-1
  ------------name: User 1
  ------------email: user1@domain.com
  ------------loginType:facebook
  ------------id: user-id-1 
  --------user-id-2
  ------------name: User 2
  ------------email: user2@domain.com
  ------------loginType:email
  ------------id: user-id-2 
  ---etc
```

This way if a user claims to have forgotten their password, you can do a quick lookup via email and obtain the users id. For the Realtime Database I would recommend denormalize your data a bit more so that you can retrieve user id's by email. This is what I mean

```
my-app
  --users
  --------user-id-1
  ------------name: User 1
  ------------email: user1@domain.com
  ------------id: user-id-1
  --------user-id-2
  ------------name: User 2
  ------------email: user2@domain.com
  ------------loginType:email
  ------------id: user-id-2  
  --users-by-email
  --------user1@domain.com
  ------------user-id-1
  --------user2@domain.com
  ------------user-id-2
```

In this case you can easily find the users id based on their email if you search the users-by-email field and insert the users email as a key. It should return the `userid`.

In `Firestore`, I believe you can easily query for this without having to denormalize your data.

2. Once you have access to the `users-id` and `email`, you can follow this [guide by @JenPerson from the `Firebase` team on how to mint your own Authentication tokens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtYzHTXHBp0), that will let Firebase know you are re-authenticating a specified user with different credentials