# unable to get refresh token from FirebaseAuth in xamarin android

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign in with google using

```
IAuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential as AuthCredential);
```

then I can get the idToken using

```
var token = user.User.GetIdToken(false);
```

but there is no way to get the refresh token to store it in order to check if it is valid or not.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use the refresh token yourself. This is handled behind the scenes from the Firebase SDK so you will remain connected so long as you do not sign out. The tokes expire after one hour but they will be automatically refreshed. You can revoke a refresh token using the Admin SDK. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Comment: I am trying to keep track of the auth user created after sign in, if the google user I signed in with is disabled from firebase console or it was deleted. So I am using also Admin SDK to verifyIdToken but even if the user was disabled it is still considered as a valid id token if it is not expired. any idea about this?

Comment: This could be monitored through a Cloud Function and revoke the user's refresh token if he was disabled or deleted.

Comment: Any idea where to find something like that? example or repo or any thing

Comment: Here you go:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

Comment: Check this also: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion

Comment: just one more question, if the google user has reset his google password then firebase user will be invalidated automatically or also I must handle this?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725688/firebaseauth-let-user-change-password-using-any-provider-android.
 The user is still able to login to your app, authentication process is dealt directly with the service provider